# Calculate time lags from phase angle differences/phase arrows from waveletComp in r

Tags: time-series, wavelet, phase

I am looking at associations between biological and physical variables in time-frequency domain using wavelets and would like to look at the lags between two variables for specific time scales/periods.

To do that I calculated and plotted wavelet coherence and phase angles using the WaveletComp package in R from two time series of daily resolution.

I was able to extract smoothed phase angle differences (sAngle) for specific periods (or band of periods) using the `wc.sel.phases()` function. sAngle is expressed in radians (-pi to pi).

I would like to transform these sAngle values to time lags in days but not sure how to do that.